# Select posts from Category - Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to filter posts from category.

This category is called "images"

And I have the code below:

```
<div id="owl-images" class="owl-carousel">
    <?php query_posts('category_name=images'); ?>
    <?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
      <?php
      $src = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID), array( 5600,1000 ), false, '' );?>
      <a href='<?php echo $src[0]; ?>' data-lightbox="image-77" data-title="<?php the_title() ?>">
      <div class="item">
        <div class="lazyOwl" style="background:url(<?php echo $src[0]; ?>) no-repeat center center;background-size:cover;height:300px;" alt=""></div>
      </div>
    </a>
    <?php endwhile; endif; ?>
  </div>
```

The problem is that:

- It is displaying some posts from other categories
- It is not displaying all posts from category "image"

What is wrong with the code?

PS: I have seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17470563/wordpress-get-featured-image-url-from-category) answer and it didn't help. Remained the same.

Best regards.

Comment: You should try with `cat=cat_id` instead of `category_name`.

Comment: Ok, so I notice now it does filter and shows only images from `images` Category but it displays only the last 10 posts. It is like the `showposts` default value is 10. How can I change this? I want to display all of them.

Comment: Go to setting -> reading -> Blog pages show at most. You can change your default posts show option from here.

Comment: Oh that's it! You should post both your comments as an answer, because it is the accepted answer.

Comment: Now you can accept my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try with

> cat=cat_id

instead of

> category_name

For change Your default show posts per page:

> Go to setting -> reading -> Blog pages

Answer (score 1):

try like this

```
query_posts( array ( 'category_name' => 'images' ) );
```

you need to pass the slug of category image in this case.

You can also try with this as well

```
$catIDs = get_cat_ID('images');
query_posts("cat=$catIDs");
```

Answer (score 0):

Use  category__in and pass your category id

```
<?php query_posts('category__in=cat_id'); ?>
```